# connect to a database with T4?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

how can I connect to a local database with T4?, I try these code but it not working
Iam using vs.net 2010 and SQL2008 with windows authentication, Iam trying to connect to my local server, to that database to get their properties

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common" #>


namespace T4SNUG.Entities
{

<# Server server = new Server(".");
Database db = server.Databases["Chinook"]};#>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should work.

Are you seeing an error message or exception in the output window?

I can use the following code in a T4:

```
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common" #>


<# 
    var server = new Server(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
    var db = server.Databases["moviereviews"];
    foreach(var property in db.GetType()
                              .GetProperties()
                              .Where(p=>p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
    {
#>
        <#= property.Name #> : <#= property.GetValue(db, null) #>
<#      
    }
#>
```

and it gives me:

```
Name : moviereviews
Collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
DatabaseSnapshotBaseName : 
DefaultFileGroup : PRIMARY
DefaultFileStreamFileGroup : 
DefaultFullTextCatalog : 
DefaultSchema : dbo
MirroringPartner : 
MirroringPartnerInstance : 
MirroringWitness : 
...
```